# Spring Bean ID Scope

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have multiple spring configuration files, where each defines beans for a different implementation of an interface. Therefore the contents are similar, but not identical.

Each contains a bean that, through its `<constructor-arg>` references another bean defined in the file. This referenced bean exists in all of the config files with the same name. My IDE (IntelliJ) prompts me as to which version of the bean I want to use (from which config file) but it seems to get a bit confused when I ctrl click the reference.

So I want to clarify the scope of how these config files are resolved - does spring always look for the bean definition inside the same file first?

Comment: try this http://spring.io/blog/2011/02/14/spring-3-1-m1-introducing-profile/

Answer (score 0):

During the spring bean initialization phase, all bean definitions are loaded first before anything else happens. Bean instantiation and dependency injection are done in later step.Therefore it should not matter to which configuration file was each bean defined.